# Synchronization done by class destructors

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, thread-synchronization

I've got question about multithreading. I have a pretty big project and now I am writing some exe client to use all of that code. It involves multithreading and inter-process communication. I've got main which looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
std::unique_ptr<CommunicationWrapper> wrapper;

wrapper = std::make_unique<CommunicationWrapper>(argv[1]);
wrapper->run();

return 0;
}
```

Underneath there is a class which is doing inter-process communication which looks like this:

```
CommunicationEngine::CommunicationEngine()
 : m_processingLoop(std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() { processingLoop(); }))
{}

CommunicationEngine::~CommunicationEngine()
{
   m_processingLoop.wait();
}

//some long function that do a lot of stuff based on messages from anothre process
void CommunicationEngine::processingLoop() const
```

This code work without a problem but I want to know if it is considered good practice and good design to do the synchronization (waiting) on call of destructor? What are possible pitfals of that approach?

Comment: The standard library does it. The destructor of `std::future` will block if it's the last one referring to shared state created in a call to `std::async`, and the state isn't ready yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) in general is a very useful idiom, it makes your code exception-safe and reduces risk of mistakes to appear during further modification.

The main thing you should do - is to make sure your destructor will not throw.

Regarding exception safety of [`std::future::wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait) - it's behavior is undefined when `valid() == false` before `wait()`, so you should rather check for that before calling it in desctructor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need any `unique_ptr` in provided code. Just 
`CommunicationWrapper(argv[1]).run()` will do.

Second of all, I see no problem what you are doing **in general**. It's ok to wait for the thread to complete in destructor. However, you should realize that your application will not exit until the thread terminates, so if there is a bug in it, your application will never exit. Sometime people prefer to do timed waits and than exit after a certain time.